# True or False: If the function $(f + g)(x)$ is continuous, then the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The full question comes from Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick, Section 3.1, Question 1a

**Determine if the following is true or false and justify answer**

> If $f + g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous

My intuition tells me this is false, but when I work through it I'm arriving at something that looks like True

**My attempt**

This is of form $P \rightarrow Q$ so it will be False when we have $True \rightarrow False$.

Assume $f + g$ is continuous. Our goal is of form
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = x_0 \rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) = f(x_0) \quad \wedge \quad \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = x_0 \rightarrow \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}g(x_n) = g(x_0)$$

We can prove each separately. Note that each is of the form $P \rightarrow Q$ so we will assume $P$ again and show $Q$.

Let $x_0$ be arbitrary and assume $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = x_0$.

\begin{align}
   \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = x_0 \rightarrow&& &\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(f+g)(x_n) = (f+g)(x_0) &&\text{assumption and definition of continuity} \tag 1\\
   \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = x_0 \rightarrow&& &\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) + g(x_n) = f(x_0) + g(x_0) && \text{def. of sum of functions} \tag 2\\
   \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n = x_0 \rightarrow&& &\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) + \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}g(x_n) = f(x_0) + g(x_0) && \text{sum property of limits} \tag 3
\end{align}

At this point it seems like you can get $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) = f(x_0)$ and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}g(x_n) = g(x_0)$ which would show this all to be true, however I don't think that is a valid step.

That being said, that doesn't prove it False - I think I need a counterexample but I'm not seeing one.

Any help is appreciated to refine this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false. Let $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 &\text{if } x \lt 0 \\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and let $g\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be:
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } x \lt 0 \\
-1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then $f$ and $g$ are not continuous at $x = 0$, but their sum is the zero function, which is continuous everywhere.

Comment: So obvious now, thanks for the clear example!

Answer (score 2):

take $f(x)$ to be constantly 0 for $x<0$ and constantly 1 for $x\geq 0$, then g to be constantly 0 for $x<0$ and constantly -1 for $x\geq 0$. The sum is the constant zero function which is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have provided you with the counterexamples you need, but as to where you went wrong, it's in your third item, the one you labelled "sum property of limits", where you seem to have used

$$ \lim (f+g) = \lim f + \lim g,$$

which is true SO LONG AS we know that $\lim f$ and $\lim g$ exist. Which you don't.

Comment: Oh yea I see that now, really appreciate that because I was wondering where I was going wrong in my approach.

Comment: All those theorems start with a list of pre-conditions, but it's really tempting to just use the result without verifying them. :-)