# True or false: If the function $f + g$ is continuous and $g$ is continuous, then $f$ is also continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

This question comes from Advanced Calculus by Fitzpatrick, Chapter 3, Section 3.1 Exercise 1c. I wrote a [similar question today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930432/true-or-false-if-the-function-f-gx-is-continuous-then-the-functions-f/3930461?noredirect=1#comment8105762_3930461) and so I think I'm getting the hang of this.

**My question is:** is my proof/justification correct? If not, why?

> If the functions $ f + g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, then function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also continuous

My attempt

Since $g$ is continuous, then so is $-g$. Note that $(f + g) + (-g) = f$. Since $f$ is the sum of continuous functions, $f$ is continuous. Therefore this statement is true.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Yes, it's totally correct and formal.

Comment: Awesome thank you

Comment: This is correct because $cf(x)$ is continuous for any constant $c$ and continuous function $f(x)$. However, the other question you asked about limit of sum of two functions cannot be treated similarly.